# many pandas dataframe to in one readeable file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

```
a=np.array([[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3]])
df=pandas.DataFrame(a)
df.to_html('table.html')
```

I am trying to make pandas.DataFrame to html.
The data are from csv.file, and i split it to several table. 
i want make table are in one file one by one.(it's not linked together)

```
open(filename, mode):
```

> it likes  file open with mode 'a',no overwrite original file.

Sample output table  like this. 
How can i do that or are there another more readable way ?

[image]

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out what you really want. Perhaps you can update the question with some sample output.

Comment: Use pd.concat... `df_out = pd.concat([df_a,df_b,df_c])`

Comment: Indeed very unclear what you want. Always try to show the **expected output**.

Comment: i have update.Sorry,i try my best to explain.
If it is still not clear,i will edit again.
My english is not good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can proceed as follows:

- put all your dataframes in a list
- iterate through them and convert each one to HTML
- concatenate all the HTML outputs to one single file

---

In terms of code, here's how you can do that:

```
a=np.array([[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3]])
b=np.array([[1,4,5,1],[12,2,32,2],[3,32,30,3]])
df_a = pd.DataFrame(a)
df_b = pd.DataFrame(b)
list_df = [df_a, df_b]
output = ""
for index, df in enumerate(list_df):
     output += df.to_html() + '<br>'      

with open('output.html', 'w') as f:
     f.writelines(output)
```

---

Here's how the ouput looks like:

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>0</th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table><br><table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>0</th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table><br>
```